# kafka-lag-exporter don't show lags when consumer group read 2 or more topics

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, monitoring, metrics, lag

I am testing [kafka-lag-exporer](https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter) . I setup kafka-server, zookeper, prometheus and grafana on my local machine. I created a Kafka topic named `topic_1` and consumer group `group1` that read messages from `topic_1`. I produced some messages (all using Kafka cli) and the consumer group read them. Then I stopped consumer group cli and produced some more messages to `topic_1` to make lags. Everything worked fine, kafka-lag-exporter exposed metric `kafka_consumergroup_group_lag` for `group="group1",topic="topic_1"`

Then I added a new topic with the name topic_2 and created some messages there, stopped consumer group, and created another 3 messages to make lags. Now there is no metric `kafka_consumergroup_group_lag` for `group="group1",topic="topic_2"` . As you can in screenshot kafka cli show the lags for consumer group group1 and topic `topic_2.`

[topic_1 active, topic_2 has lags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hta7N.png)

Then I stopped consumer group `group1` from reading any topic. And metrics appear

```
# TYPE kafka_consumergroup_group_lag gauge
kafka_consumergroup_group_lag{location="local",cluster_name="kafka",group="group1",topic="topic_1",partition="0",member_host="unknown",consumer_id="unknown",client_id="unknown",} 0.0
kafka_consumergroup_group_lag{location="local",cluster_name="kafka",group="group1",topic="topic_2",partition="0",member_host="unknown",consumer_id="unknown",client_id="unknown",} 3.0
```

[stopped consumer group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YJrP.png)

but when I run consumer group to consume one topic I have these metrics in lag-exporter

```
# HELP kafka_consumergroup_group_lag Group offset lag of a partition
# TYPE kafka_consumergroup_group_lag gauge
kafka_consumergroup_group_lag{location="local",cluster_name="kafka",group="group1",topic="topic_1",partition="0",member_host="/192.168.65.1",consumer_id="console-consumer-565052f6-8883-4594-831a-76e271b04edc",client_id="console-consumer",} 0.0
```

Kafka lag-exporter version is 0.7.0 it is running in standalone mode and configuration is very basic.

```
kafka-lag-exporter {
  reporters.prometheus.port = 7070
  clusters = [
    {
      name = "kafka"
      bootstrap-brokers = "kafka:9092"
      labels = {
        location = "local"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What you report feels like an error in exporters behaviour. Consider checking the DEBUG output as [recommended in repo](https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter#troubleshooting) and if it doesn't help reporting an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing a tool. Instead of [kafka-lag-exporter](https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter) I now use [kafka_exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) It shows lags even if there is no active consumer to the topic.